# How can I change the height of an UIImageView programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I am teaching myself Swift through taking a hands-on approach. I have a simple image that has a height constraint with a constant of 150 set in the storyboard. However I would like to change it to 70 programmatically.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let tableElement = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FirstTable", for: indexPath) 
    tableElement.BigImage.image = ?? 
    return tableElement
}
```

I have access to the image by doing `tableElement.BigImage.image`, and I would like to find the height property of it and set it to 70. I have tried this `tableElement.BigImage.image.topCapHeight = 70` however that gives an error. How can I do this?

This is my outlet to it

```
    class myNewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var BigImage: UIImageView!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

I am trying to learn how to change the height of the image programmatically because I am getting 2 different batches of images and I want to separate them by height sort of a red/blue thing.

Comment: Create a outlet for that height constraint of imageView, change the constraint constant to 70. Also, you are trying to change the image rather than the height constraint of imageView

Comment: @New16 You cant make any outlet for dynamic cells.

Comment: @Lumialxk OP can make an outlet to the `UITableViewCell` for the height constraint of the `UIImageView` and update it accordingly in `cellForRow`

Comment: Oh ok thanks will do that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-click to edit constraint. Set identifier for it.
[image]

And find it programmatically.

```
for constraint in UIView().constraints {
    if constraint.identifier == "your identifier" {
        // set here
    }
}
```

**Update**
As you created a custom cell, to add another outlet is better. CTRL-DRAG an outlet, it will look like this.

```
class myNewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var BigImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var topCapHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that is exactly what I needed